# Deleting or removing users from a workflow, after if they no longer need to complete the task

Tags: workflow, delete

A user has created a workflow with multiple participants. One of the participants assigned a task, no longer needs to complete that task. How can we remove the user or task without the workflow status changing to  reject?

Comment: I didn't really worked on workflows a lot but I guess you can add a event receiver on Item update and then pro-grammatically remove all participants other then the one who assigned the task.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about, see http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/close-old-unanswered-question